# Set clicklistener on specific part of spannable textview in android

Tags: android

I am having a difficulty in setting a `ClickListener` in specific part of Text in `SpannableTextView` in android.

I have this text:

> By registering you agree to the **Terms And Services**

I want to set clicklistener to the bold part only? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
private void prepareTerms(){
    String termsAndConditionsText = ...;
    String discoverTermsText = ...;

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(discoverTermsText);
    int index = discoverTermsText.indexOf(termsAndConditionsText);
    ss.setSpan(
            new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    // open a webview here if you want
                }
            },
            index,
            index + termsAndConditionsText.length(),
            SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    );
    mTermAndCondTextView.setText(ss);
    mTermAndCondTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: it seems legit will try!!

Comment: can you define termsAndConditionsText and discoverTermsText? because it says IndexOutOfBoundsError

Comment: for example 
   ```
 String termsAndConditionsText = "Terms and Conditions";
     String discoverTermsText = "I have read and accept " + termsAndConditionsText;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
    // click function
    }
 }, start_index, end_index, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textview.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
    String text1 = "By registering you agree to the" + " ";
    String text2 = "Terms And Services";

    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text1 + text2);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // listen click here
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(true);
            ds.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    };

    spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, text1.length(), text1.length() + text2.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textview.setText(spannableString);
    textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textview.setHighlightColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method **setSpan** from the class android.text.Spannable

Complete example and necessary information provided in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int))

In your string "By registering you agree to the Terms And Services" start value would be 35 and end would be `stringObj.length`